# CakePHP: how to specify returned fields when there are multiple associated records

Tags: php, cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0, query-optimization

I'm doing a `find('all')` with a fairly complex set of conditions:

```
array(
    'conditions' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Attempt.test_id = 8',
        (int) 1 => 'Attempt.score > 60',
        (int) 2 => array(),
        (int) 3 => array(
            (int) 0 => 'Resume.has_file = 1'
        )
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'table' => 'attempts',
            'alias' => 'Attempt',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                (int) 0 => 'Attempt.user_id = User.id AND Attempt.test_id != 5'
            )
        )
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Resume',
        (int) 1 => 'Attempt',
        (int) 2 => 'Tag'
    ),
    'group' => 'User.id',
    'limit' => (int) 1,
    'fields' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'User.id',
        (int) 1 => 'Resume.id'
    )
)
```

The returned data looks like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '381'
        ),
        'Resume' => array(
            'id' => '15'
        ),
        'Attempt' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '16072',
                'user_id' => '381',
                'test_id' => '8',
                'status' => 'complete'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'id' => '16073',
                'user_id' => '381',
                'test_id' => '8',
                'status' => 'complete'
            )
```

The query is taking forever and a day to run and I only need the User.id, so I'm trying to strip out the unneeded fields. It's working for the hasOne associations, but the hasMany doesn't match the syntax in the documentation. For example, `'limit'=>array('Attempt.id')` throws errors because there is no $user['Attempt']['id']. Instead it's $user['Attempt'][#]['id'].

How do I do this? I'd also love to hear any other advice that will speed up this query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I would do.

first, I see that you only need User.id, however I see you that you are adding more associations in the contain, thus I would remove "Tag".

I see that you are doing a manual join of the type left, which is what CakePHP uses by default, yes I see you are setting an additional condition there, even though there is nothing wrong with it I would simply bind Attempt model on the fly with the aforementioned condition, that is

```
$this->User->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Attempt'))); 
//I dont know if its a hasMany, I just assumed that
$this->User->bindMode(array('hasMany'=> array(
    'Attempt' => array('conditions' => array('Attempt.test_id <>' => 5)))));
```

Repeat with Resume model.

I see you are grouping, yet I don't see any aggregate function, why are you grouping in there? what do you need? Can it be solved with Hash::extrat()?

Another thing to look at: run the query directly in your Database console and see if there are indexes that could help you.

Lastly, I am not sure about your requirements but should both conditions (in Attempt and Resume models) be met? if that is the case then you need "inner join"

Comment: Thanks Guillermo. I should have clarified that even though this query does not have any conditions on the Tag model, many of them will. So I can't get away with removing that, or any of the associations.

Comment: Ok, maybe if you tell us the complete set of conditions and what you need from this query we can better help you.

Comment: These are the complete set of conditions. I just need to get the User.id. All the other inclusions are just filters. The various conditions reference those tables.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I have to overtly "join" the Attempts table. The hasMany association is set correctly in the models, but the I get errors unless I `join` it manually.

Comment: I get errors about CakePHP not recognizing the field name from attempts table if I use one in where condition or something.

Comment: would you PLEASE paste here the message?

Comment: This is the error I see if I do not add the 'joins' the search options: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Attempt.score' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Here is the query it was attempting: `SELECT `User`.`id`
FROM `users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `resumes` AS `Resume` ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`id` IN (SELECT `User1`.`id` FROM `users` AS User1 
LEFT JOIN `tags_users` AS TagUser ON (`User1`.`id`= `TagUser`.`user_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS Tag ON (`TagUser`.`tag_id`= `Tag`.`id`) 
WHERE `Tag`.`id` = (2) ) AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1 GROUP BY `User`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Attempt`.`score` DESC 
LIMIT 25
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42044/discussion-between-guillemo-mansilla-and-emerson)

Comment: I created a new question to address the issue with the mandatory join in the search options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244368/cakephp-hasmany-association-not-recognized