# CakePHP: hasMany association not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Attempts belong to Users (Users have many Attempts).

In User.php (model)

```
public $hasMany = array (
    'Attempt'   =>  array(
        'className'     =>  'Attempt',
        'order' => 'modified DESC'
    ), 
);
```

In Attempt.php (model)

```
    public $belongsTo = array (
        'Test' => array ('className' => 'Test', 'foreignKey'=>'test_id', 'order' => 'Test.created DESC'),
        'User' => array ('className' => 'User', 'order' => 'User.created DESC')
    );
```

In a controller, I construct this query...

```
$joins = array(

        array( 
            'table'=>'attempts',
            'alias'=>'Attempt',
            'type'=>'LEFT',
            'conditions'=>array("Attempt.user_id = User.id AND Attempt.test_id != {$practice_test_id}")
        )

    );

$conditions[] = array('Resume.has_file = 1');

$search_options = array( 'conditions'=>$conditions, 
    //'joins' => $joins, //<--I'M FORCED TO USER THIS TO GET THIS TO WORK
    'contain' => array('Resume', 'Attempt', 'Tag'),
    'order' => array('Attempt.score'=> 'DESC'),
    'group' => 'User.id'
);
$paginator_settings = $search_options;
$paginator_settings['limit'] = 25;
$this->Paginator->settings = $paginator_settings;

$resume_display_array = $this->Paginator->paginate('User');
```

(It looks a bit strange here because I stripped out a lot of distracting logic that happens in between the construction of this query. Most of these conditions are built dynamically based on user input.)

When I leave out the `$search_options['joins]` this does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Attempt.score' in 'order clause'
```

The SQL dump looks something like this:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`
FROM `users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `resumes` AS `Resume` ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `User`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `User1`.`id` FROM `users` AS User1 
    LEFT JOIN `tags_users` AS TagUser ON (`User1`.`id`= `TagUser`.`user_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `tags` AS Tag ON (`TagUser`.`tag_id`= `Tag`.`id`) 
    WHERE `Tag`.`id` = (2) ) AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1 GROUP BY `User`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Attempt`.`score` DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Why isn't the Attempt model getting included automatically due to its hasMany relationship with User?

Comment: If you copy and paste that SQL in your database does it return something?
Does "score" column exist in Attempts table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem here. In fact, isn't the answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245673/cakephp-finding-across-associated-models-works-differently-than-documentation-c) posted today?

> But this is not the case with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany
>   associations. Here is where forcing joins comes to the rescue. You
>   only have to define the necessary joins to combine tables and get the
>   desired results for your query.

So, from what I understand, you have to force the join relation when talking about a `hasMany`, right? That's what you are doing when using the `$joins` array. Since a `User hasMany Attempt`, then you'll have to force the join. Now, that probably won't be necessary if you where paginating from the `Attempt`'s point of view. If you do a `$this->Paginator->paginate('Attempt');` (changing the necessary relations and conditions), you wouldn't need to join the user table manually to get the data.

And so, if the `Attempt` doesn't join by itself (as per the docs says), then the order condition creates a problem because the `Attempt` data is retrieved in another query and the table reference is lost in the first query. Solution: do the join, cake is behaving as expected.

Comment: The other question is about conflicting information in the CakePHP documentation (in a section relevant to this issue). It is/was not clear to me what the expected behavior should be. Your point about the "perspective" of the Paginator is well-taken, but aren't we paginating the 'User' model, which hasMany 'Attempts'? So shouldn't we expect the automagic to work without the forced join? In case it's relevant, the query is made from inside a different controller after using loadModel('User').

Comment: I know it's not a duplicate question, I just pointed it out because I got the solution from there. But look, if we are paginating the User model, we shouldn't expect the automagic to work because the documentation says *it won't work* unless you force it, doesn't matter from which controller you do the query: **hashMany and HABTM associations needs to be forcefully joined**.

Comment: I know the docs say that but it isn't working that way for us anywhere else. We have several other examples of models with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany associations which appear automatically without any joins. That's the basis of the mystery. But let's chat or post subsequent comments over there so as not to get off track here.

Comment: Can you post another example where it has worked the other way? To see what you mean.

Comment: It will get confusing to add it here because you'll need to see both models and the find() in the controller and the returned data. I can show you in chat or I can add those details to the other ticket later.

Comment: Just figured out how to create a chat :P http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42060/cakephp-hasmany-discussion

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a typo in  your hasMany association -- className has a capital N.

I would also try testing `$this->User->recursive = 2; $this->User->find('first');`, just to see what it returns.  If the results don't include Attempt, I would assume there's something wrong with how you set up the model relationships.

Comment: Thanks. The `className` is a typo which I'll fix momentarily. As for the model relationships... they're posted above. Do you see anything wrong with them?

Comment: I don't see anything that stands out other than className.  I just suggested checking because the behavior you're seeing is like the association is not working.

Comment: I agree that it's not working. Figuring out why is the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

**try this it'll work**

```
  $this->User->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array(
            'FollowUp' => array('className' => 'FollowUp', 'foreignKey' => 'publisher_id',
            'fields' => array('amount'),
        ),
        'SchoolFollow' => array('className' => 'SchoolFollow', 'foreignKey' => 'publisher_id',
            'fields' => array('amount'),
        ),
        'TravelerFollow' => array('className' => 'TravelerFollow', 'foreignKey' => 'publisher_id',
            'fields' => array('amount'),
        ),
        $mdl . 'Cashback' => array('className' => $mdl . 'Cashback', 'foreignKey' => 'publisher_id',
            'fields' => array('admin_comission_amount'),
            'conditions' => array('status' => 'done')
        ),
)));
```