# CakePHP: Finding across associated models works differently than documentation claims

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

The [CakePHP 2.0 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) says the following:

> In CakePHP **some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) performs automatic
>   joins** to retrieve data, so you can issue queries to retrieve models
>   based on data in the related one.
>
> But **this is not the case with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany
>   associations**. Here is where forcing joins comes to the rescue. You
>   only have to define the necessary joins to combine tables and get the
>   desired results for your query.

But I'm seeing different behavior in two ways:

1. All my hasAndBelongsToMany associations are joined automatically (unless I tell them not to using `$options['contain']=...` when I search.
2. In one situation, I CAN'T get a hasMany association to appear unless I force it with `$options['joins']=...`

The latter problem may be something I've done wrong, but it's difficult to troubleshoot without knowing how it SHOULD work. I suspect that the documentation is either inaccurate on this point, or perhaps it works completely differently when the containable component is in use. (NOTE: We have `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in our AppModel so all models inherit it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define containable behavior at top of every model use has many or HABBTM,  like

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
..................
```

You can use also use `$options['contain']=...` which fetch related data auto magically.

Also you can set value of recussrisive to fetch associated data like

```
$this->MyModel->recursive = 1;
```

Comment: We define `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in the AppModel so all models inherit it. I don't think recursive is the solution to this problem but I'll do some tests anyway.